# Where does Linux store logs of WiFi networks when searching? Does it at all?

Tags: linux, debian, wifi

For research I wanted to try and keep a log of all the networks that my laptop sees (not connects connects to, but just gets a response from when searching) over a period of time walking around. I was curious if it saved this info to a cache file somewhere in the system or if I could make it do so.

If it's relevant, I'm running the Debian derivative, CrunchBang.  I'm fairly new to Linux and now I've finally found a purpose for using it!

Comment: You may also want to look at passive monitors like Kismet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You normally scan to get WiFi available network. You can `iwlist scan` or `iw dev wlan0 scan` and dump the output to any file. You need it to run this periodically then put it in to a cronjob.

Comment: Oh sweet, so I can force it to scan for WiFi and then dump directly from there?  I'll try it out.  Thanks a lot!